# Implementing an observable settings class

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Using Rx, I have a settings panel which controls whether operations are enabled and at what rate they should run.
These are stored in a LibrarySettings class, when there is a change to the property via a front end slider/checkbox the observable property picks up on the change.

How should I write the LibrarySettings class such that the it does not set the setting.Value (whole LibrarySettings instance) to null.

```
IDisposable reader = setting.Value.Subscribe(options =>
{
    OperationOneEnabled = options.OperationOneEnabled;
    OperationTwoEnabled = options.OperationTwoEnabled;

    OperationOneRate = options.OperationOneRate;
    OperationTwoRate = options.OperationTwoRate;     
});

IDisposable writer = this.WhenAnyPropertyChanged()
    .Subscribe(vm =>
    {
        settings.Write(new LibrarySettings(OperationOneEnabled, OperationOneRate,
            OperationTwoEnabled, OperationTwoRate));
    });

OperationOneRateProperty = this.WhenValueChanged(vm => vm.ScheduleRate)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Select(value => $"{value} seconds")
    .ForBinding();

 _CleanUp = new CompositeDisposable(reader, writer, OperationOneRateProperty);
```

So within the LibrarySettings class I need to be able to create the property

```
public IObservable<LibrarySettings> Value
{
    get { return _Value; }
    set { _Value = value; }
}
```

So I try the following

```
Value = Observable.Create<LibrarySettings>(() =>
{
    new LibrarySettings(false, OperationOneEnable,OperationOneRate,
        OperationTwoEnabled, OperationTwoRate);
});
```

and get a

> `delegate func<IObserver<LibrarySettings>> does not take 0 arguments`

Comment: Why do you think the setting.Value would become null?

Comment: @BuhBuh 
It is null, when the LibrarySettings class is initiated the first time. i.e 'new LibrarySettings(true,20,true,30)' those enabled and rate properties are set but value isn't

Comment: Are you using ReactiveUI?

Comment: @Shlomo No, and I don't want to introduce that dependency.

Comment: @Mdev - Have you looked at the signature for `Observable.Create`?

Comment: @Mdev - Could you post the definition of `LibrarySettings`?

Comment: @Enigmativity please check out github link below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this is not valid code (wont compile)

```
Value = Observable.Create<LibrarySettings>(() =>
{
    new LibrarySettings(false, OperationOneEnable,OperationOneRate,
        OperationTwoEnabled, OperationTwoRate);
});
```

Observable.Create generally takes a `Func<IObserver<T>, IDisposable>` as a parameter, so should be corrected to be

```
Value = Observable.Create<LibrarySettings>(observer =>
{
    observer.OnNext(new LibrarySettings(/*args*/));
    //What to do here?
    return Disposable.Empty; //Yuck.
});
```

Probably better and more simple is to just use `Observable.Return`, but then what is observable about this. Seems like it is using Rx just to satisfy a signature, because this isn't in the spirit of Rx.

Instead I imagine what you really want is a `Settings` property that pushes notifications when it changes. To this end I think there are two reasonable approaches

1. You have a readonly property of `LibrarySettings` where the the type `LibrarySettings` is mutable and observable.
2. You have a mutable and observable property of `LibrarySettings`, but the type `LibrarySettings` is immuatable.

i.e. either the readonly property

```
this.Setting.WhenAnyPropertyChanged()....

this.Setting.OperationOneRate = 25;
this.Setting.IsOperationOneEnabled= true;
```

where the type is mutable

```
public class LibrarySettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LibrarySettings()
    {
        IsOperationOneEnabled = false;;
        OperationOneRate = 0;
        IsOperationTwoEnabled = false;
        OperationTwoRate = 0;
    }
    public bool IsOperationOneEnabled { get;set; }
    public double OperationOneRate { get; set; }
    public bool IsOperationTwoEnabled { get;set; }
    public double OperationTwoRate { get; set;}

    #region INPC Impl
    #region
}
```

Or the immutable type, and you mutate the property (with a new instance each time). You would obviously want to create it with a default value.

```
this.WhenValueChanges(t=>t.Setting)....

this.Setting = new LibrarySettings(OperationOneEnable, OperationOneRate,
    OperationTwoEnabled, OperationTwoRate);
```

And the type like...

```
public class LibrarySettings
{
    public LibrarySettings(bool isOperationOneEnabled, double operationOneRate,
        bool isOperationTwoEnabled, double operationTwoRate)
    {
        IsOperationOneEnabled = isOperationOneEnabled;
        OperationOneRate = operationOneRate;
        IsOperationTwoEnabled = isOperationTwoEnabled;
        OperationTwoRate = operationTwoRate;
    }
    public bool IsOperationOneEnabled { get; }
    public double OperationOneRate { get; }
    public bool IsOperationTwoEnabled { get; }
    public double OperationTwoRate { get;}
}
```

I just found the code that you linked to (you linked to the root of the repo not the actual classes in question)
* https://github.com/markiemarkus/Amadeus/blob/master/Amadeus/NovoApp/Models/LibrarySettings.cs

- https://github.com/markiemarkus/Amadeus/blob/master/AmadeusNovoApp/Models/View/LibraryOptionsViewModel.cs

The main issue is these lines here

```
Value = Observable.Create<LibrarySettings>(observer =>
{
    observer.OnNext(new LibrarySettings(false, OperationOneEnabled, OperationOneRate, OperationTwoEnabled, OperationTwoRate));
    return Disposable.Empty;
});
```

}

```
public IObservable<LibrarySettings> Value
{
     get { return _Value; }
     set { _Value = value; }
}

public void Write(LibrarySettings item)
{
     Value = Observable.Create<LibrarySettings>(observer =>
    {
        observer.OnNext(new LibrarySettings(false, OperationOneEnabled,
        OperationOneRate, OperationTwoEnabled, OperationTwoRate));
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
}
```

You create an observable sequence that has a single value (so isn't really observable). You then expose it via a property with a public setter (what does a settable IObservable property mean?!). And lastly you write over that instance in your write method, meaning anyone that has actually subscribed to the original value of the property is left holding a subscription to an orphaned Observable Sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to get past the compile error, you would win with this:

```
Value = Observable.Return(new LibrarySettings(/*args*/));
```

or this:

```
Value = Observable.Create<LibrarySettings>(observer =>
{
    observer.OnNext(new LibrarySettings(/*args*/));
    return Disposable.Empty;
});
```

It sounds like you have a bigger design problem that you haven't laid out though.

Comment: please check out https://github.com/markiemarkus/Amadeus---Copy

However yes this is a win to get past the compile error

Comment: Returning `Disposable.Empty` is such a bad anti-pattern. I would strongly suggest to the OP that they avoid this particular `Observable.Create` variant.

Comment: Why antipattern? The two are functionally equivalent.